# Hibernate Reverse Engineer Database

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, reverse-engineering, pojo

I am using MyEclipse to generate Hibernate code for a PostgreSQL database. The issue is that this is the only reason I'm using MyEclipse. I would like to use some kind of command line tool to easily generate this code. I've seen some mention of such tools but I can't find anything solid. It seems like what I want to do is pretty simple. I hate to fire up this IDE and go through all this stuff just to do some simple code gen.

What's the best way to do this simply?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using ant from command line like [this](http://www.factorypattern.com/howto-generate-hibernate-pojo-and-mapping-files-using-ant-from-a-db-schema/).